# Docker Compose - A debugger operation is taking a long time to complete

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently running VS 2019 16.9.4. I have Docker Engine 20.10.5. It is using WSL 2.

I'm using docker-compose in visual studio. The Dockerfile is using aspnet:5.0.5-buster-slim.

When I fire up docker-compose and set a breakpoint, everything works until the breakpoint is hit. Then a popup appears that says "A debugger operation is taking a long time to complete" and everything just hangs. I can hit the cancel button, but it doesn't do anything.

This use to work. Any idea as to why it isn't working now?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ReSharper? I had the exact same issue with VS 2019 16.10.0 and Docker Engine 20.10.6.

After updating Resharper to 2021.1.3 debugging works as expected.